# Extract multiple records from a Text File after keyword search in a specific field

Tags: c++, text, full-text-search

I'm working on a bit of code that will search tickets from a text file.  Each ticket starts with "***" and ends with "###".

(1) Search a keyword from user input in the "City" field.
(2) Return the all records and lines from that record once found, not just one.

The record looks like this:

```
***
Ticket Number : 
First Name : T
First Name : C
Address of Violations : 123 Malberry Ln.
City : Oak Park //Need user to input City and Pull all tickets from that City
Plate : Q1234
Vin Number : V1234
Violation Narrative : NO PARKING
Violation Code :V1234
Violation Amount :50
Late Fee : 100
Make : 
Model : 
Was this Paid ? : 0
Date : 1012017
Time : 1200
Pay by Date : 1012018
Officer Number : 6630
###
```

My queries have to be specific for each category.

For example, If there are three records and two are from the same city "Oak Park" I want the two "Oak Park" records to display, not just one.

How I'm starting to work this out is doing a search that pulls the record from "***" to "###" possibly like this:

```
{
ifstream in("tickets.txt");
string beforeEqual = "";
string afterEqual = "";
while (!in.eof())
{
    getline(in, beforeEqual, '***'); //grtting string upto =
    getline(in, afterEqual, '###'); //getting string after =
    cout << afterEqual << endl; //printing string after =
}
```

But I also need to incorporate a search for ("City : " + search_token).

So when I do a (City Search) it pulls all the tickets from that city.

How would this be implemented and am I on the right track?

My work so far, just a generic search:

```
void city_search() {

string search;
string line;

ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("tickets.txt");

if (!inFile) {
    cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;
    exit(1);
}

cout << "Please enter a plate Number to search : " << endl;
cin >> search;

size_t pos;
while (inFile.good())
{
    getline(inFile, line); // get line from file
    pos = line.find(search); // search
    if (pos != string::npos) // string::npos is returned if string is not found
    {
        cout << search << "Found!";
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: "My queries have to be specific for each category." - By category you mean ticket number, first name, plate, city etc.?

Comment: @JackOfBlades exactly.  I'll just replicate the function call for the City to the other categories.  I already have a working switch statement calling these functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd rather make a generic function for them all. Switches would mean more overhead in the case you describe, if I understood what you were planning initially, correctly.

What you'd rather do is something akin to this:

```
//This function compares the ticket's category's contents with the given string
std::string checkString(std::string stringToCheck) {
    std::string contentDelimiter = " : "; //Text after this will be read in
    std::string content = stringToCheck.substr(stringToCheck.find(contentDelimiter) + 
     contentDelimiter.length(), stringToCheck.length());
    //Find where the end of " : " is, read from there 'til end of line into "content"
    return content;
}

//This function opens the file, compares sought info to each relevant column,
//and types matching tickets out
void searchFile(const std::string& filePath, const int& amountOfCategories, 
                     const std::string& matchInfo, const int& categoryIndex) {
    int i = 0;
    std::string tempTicket[amountOfCategories]; 
    //Make a template to copy each ticket to for later use

    std::ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open(filePath.c_str());
    while (!inFile.eof()) { //Go through entire file
        std::getline(inFile, tempTicket[i]); //Put next line into the relevant slot
        i++;
        if (i == amountOfCategories) {
            if (matchInfo == checkString(tempTicket[categoryIndex]) {
                for (int j = 0; j < amountOfCategories; j++) { 
                         //If you want it to skip the *** and the ###, 
                         //you change it to this: int j = 1; j < amountOfCategories-1;
                    std::cout << tempTicket[j] << std::endl;
                }
                std::cout << std::endl;
            }
            i = 0;
        }
    }
    inFile.close();
}
```

Also you'll have to make the function finding category indexes, and the static string array of categories to cycle through when searching through them for the correct index. Something like this:

```
//This outside of main obviously as an independent function
int position(const std::string& soughtCategory, 
                const std::string arr[], const int& amountOfCategories) {
    int found = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i<amountOfCategories; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == soughtCategory) {
            found = i;
        }
    }
    return found;
} 

//This in main:
int amountOfCategories = 10; //Or however many there will be(no duplicates)
std::string categories[amountOfCategories];
//categories[0] = "***";
//Place all of the others between these manually
//categories[9] = "###";

//Then call it like this, for example, in main:
searchFile("file.txt", amountOfCategories, "Tampa", position("City", categories, amountOfCategories));
```